# Microsoft.Azure.Management.CosmosDB.Fluent fails when setting IpRangeFilter

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

When using the Fluent Azure Cosmos Api (1.22.2) to update the ip range:

```
var cosmos = azure.CosmosDBAccounts.GetByResourceGroup(cosmosResourceGroup, cosmosAccountName);
cosmos.Update().WithIpRangeFilter(ipRangeFilter).Apply();
```

I receive:

> Cannot update EnableMultipleWriteLocations flag and other properties
>   at the same time.\r\nActivityId: 2602d107-0e8e-4631-a421-01b65127a064,
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.4.0.0

On further inspection I can see that a Cosmos Database that has `false` set for `EnableMultipleWriteLocations` does not fail, whereas one with `true` does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as though the fluent api (or the receiving end of the API calls) is interpreting a non-specified `EnableMultipleWriteLocations` as `false`.

Therefore if you update a single property (such as IpRangeFilter) without specifying the `EnableMultipleWriteLocations` boolean for a Cosmos DB instance that has `EnableMultipleWriteLocations` set to true, it will assume you are trying to change it to false and fail (because changing from true to false is not permitted, and as they error suggests certainly not permitted with additional property changes).

My fix therefore was to manually call the [Azure REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db-resource-provider/databaseaccounts/createorupdate) and send the correct `EnableMultipleWriteLocations` value (based on a `GET` call prior to `PUT`) with the other updates.